# Trying to make std::ifstream open again

Tags: c++, ifstream, eof

I am trying to model such situation: my program has just read the last line from std::ifstream (for example, for "data.txt" text file) and makes some operations that can take much time, so somebody may append additional lines to the text file. My code here

```
while (std::getline(fs, str)) // fs is of std::ifstream type, str is std::string
        {
            //main code

             ifs.clear();  // (1)
             ifs.setstate(std::ios_base::goodbit); // (2)
        }
```

I have a breakpoint on while... line, and try to add new lines to data.txt after reading the last line from there. My first try failed. I tried to add (1), (2) or their combination to my code in order to make eofbit=false, but failed again. What else can help?

Comment: you want to read from a file while someone else is writing to it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. More precisely, it is possible that somebody added some lines in a file at the time my program was doing `//main code` section, but it's unlikely that we will use data.txt at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding it in the wrong spot. EOF is encountered in the `while`’s conditional statement, you cannot prevent it, and you cannot correct it inside the loop.

The answer is to put the read loop inside another loop:

```
while (...)
{
  fs.clear();
  std::string str;
  while (getline(fs, str))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here’s the kicker: your program will be constantly spamming the file with an EOF read attempt, which is not very CPU-friendly. You should put something in your top `while` statement’s condition to moderate that.

- Simply sleep for a short bit (like a quarter of a second)
- Wait on file update

Both require OS-specific code. The latter is preferred.
[Here’s a little library on GitHub that covers all the bases.](https://github.com/berkus/dir_monitor)

Comment: maybe worth adding that reading from a file while its being written without some synchronisation mechanism isnt a very good idea in the first place

Comment: True, but line buffering is standard behavior and typically provides sufficient synchronization points. Other issues you may encounter have to do with file locking...